# Arabic text did not show Json Android when using 3g

Tags: android, web-services, utf-8

when I use this link to get date and day in Arabic language (utf-8) 
http://iraqispring.com/apps/get_date_time.php

it is work without problems when I use **wifi**
but when I use **3g** it is get me like this text 
**Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø«Ù†ÙŠÙ† 2015-01-12**

I am using Volley library and this is the code

```
RequestQueue queuedate = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://iraqispring.com/apps/get_date_time.php";
StringRequest stringRequestDate = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object o) {
                String dateStr = o.toString();
                dateStr.getBytes();
                txtDate.setText(dateStr);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"not worked 3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

what can I do?

Comment: You should add encoding UTF-8.
Please refer to the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267616/why-does-volleys-response-string-use-an-encoding-different-from-that-in-the-res

Comment: my problem not like it

Comment: Instead of String dateStr = o.toString(); try to use String dateStr = new String(o.toString(), "UTF-8");

Comment: it get me cannot resolve constructor 'String(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)'

Comment: Use like this String response = new String(dateStr.getBytes(),"UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

While sending such kind of special characters to server you need to encode such input with the help of **URLEncoder.encode(your_input, "utf-8")** and  while receiving such kind of data first of all you need to decode it with the help of **URLDecoder.decode(your_data, "utf-8")**

I have also faced such kind of problem, so I followed encoding and decoding and resolved the problem.
I think this will help you too.

Comment: If server has encoded data then        @Override
    public void onResponse(Object o) 
 {
        String dateStr = o.toString();
        try
  {
   dateStr = URLDecoder.decode(dateStr, "utf-8");
  }
  catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        dateStr.getBytes();
        txtDate.setText(dateStr);
    }         try this and please let me know.