# VolleyPlus : NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, httprequest

I am trying to run below code:

```
Map<String, Object> requestMap = new HashMap<>();
Long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / LONG_1000;
requestMap.put(KEY_TIME, unixTime);
JWTSigner signer = new JWTSigner(SECRET);
String token = signer.sign(requestMap);
String url = BASE_URI + "/Data/Categories?d=" + token;
StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});

RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

But I am getting following error:

```
[6056] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(HttpHeaderParser.java:243)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(HttpHeaderParser.java:262)
    at com.android.volley.request.StringRequest.parseNetworkResponse(StringRequest.java:70)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:133)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

I have no idea what is to problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @blackbelt I know what is a NullPointerException. If you notice this exception doesn't come from my code directly. This is a VolleyPlus specific problem. So marking this question as duplicate is wrong.

Comment: What is `JWTSigner` ?

Comment: Java Web Token library. https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

Comment: I donot know exactly but this is the exception because of parsenetworkresponse . Try override parsenetworkresponse method in StringRequest. This  is not exactly the same but this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267616/why-does-volleys-response-string-use-an-encoding-different-from-that-in-the-res

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to override the `parseNetworkResponse` method in `StringRequest` and fix a vulnerability which does not anticipate a null header map:

```
StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}) {
    @Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        if (response.headers == null)
        {
            // cant just set a new empty map because the member is final.
            response = new NetworkResponse(
                               response.statusCode,
                               response.data,
                               Collections.<String, String>emptyMap(), // this is the important line, set an empty but non-null map.
                               response.notModified,
                               response.networkTimeMs);


        }

        return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @gil-moshayof :)

Comment: I happy that bounty haven't wasted.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered  this problem because cidEDTValue was null.

```
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("CID", cidEDTValue);
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so true. I had 8 params.put("CID", cidEDTValue) of which one of them was null. So what I did was to output each params using Toast. I got a blank toast at params(5) which signify that the value being passed was null.

Answer (score 1):

I traced the stacktrace and I believe that the root cause is `response.headers` is null in the method `parseNetworkResponse` for some reason. I would suggest the following to confirm this.

1. Create a class that extends `StringRequest`
2. In this class override the 'parseNetworkResponse()`. It should look as follows:

   ```
      protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
             Log.d("Response Header = " + response.headers);
             super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
      }
   ```
3. Use this class instead of `StringRequest`.

Once done, see if the headers is null or not. That should narrow down the problem. By the way, which version of Volley are you using. I never encountered such a problem.

Answer (score -2):

I wrote this on build.gradle.dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

And it worked.